# Calculation in Wizard

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

This is more of a general question. We have a lot of wizard, some of which start a long-running process and display the result after. The question is: what is the correct way to do long calculations?

Formerly most wizards did their calculations in `DialogPage#setVisible`, something like that:

```
public void setVisible(final boolean visible) {
    if (visible) {
        getWizard().getContainer().run(true, true, new MyCalculation());
    }
    super.setVisible(visible);
}
```

I don't think that's a good idea, since usually `getWizard()` gets called a lot in these methods. Moreover, usually the parent wizard gets cast to a specific implementation to get input values from or set the result to other pages. So usually it looks something like this:

```
public void setVisible(final boolean visible) {
    if (visible) {
        Input input = ((MyCalculationWizard)getWizard()).getInputPage().getInput();
        MyCalculation calculation = new MyCalculation(input);
        getWizard().getContainer().run(true, true, calculation);
        Output output = calculation.getOutput();
        ((MyCalculationWizard)getWizard()).getOtherPage().setOutput(output);
    }
    super.setVisible(visible);
}
```

Just from looking at the code you know that's very bad style.

So we replaced it with something that calculates in `Wizard#getNextPage()`:

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage(final IWizardPage page) {
    final IWizardPage nextPage = super.getNextPage(page);
    if (nextPage == this.myResultPage)
        getContainer().run(true, true, new MyCalculation());
    return nextPage;
}
```

That way, the wizard is able to fine-tune a lot better than a page would, and the wizard already knows it's pages and can handle input and output a lot better than a page ever could.

The drawback is: `getNextPage()` gets called a lot for updating the buttons and every time really the wizard feels like it. So while it works for small processes, it does not cut it for long-running ones.

After some more poking around I found the following to work while overriding `Wizard#setContainer`:

```
public void setContainer(final IWizardContainer wizardContainer) {
    final IWizardContainer oldContainer = getContainer();
    if (oldContainer instanceof WizardDialog) 
        ((WizardDialog) oldContainer).removePageChangingListener(this);
    super.setContainer(wizardContainer);
    if (wizardContainer instanceof WizardDialog)
        ((WizardDialog) wizardContainer).addPageChangingListener(this);
}

public void handlePageChanging(final PageChangingEvent event) {
    final IWizardPage currentPage = (IWizardPage) event.getCurrentPage();
    final IWizardPage nextPage = (IWizardPage) event.getTargetPage();

    if (currentPage == this.myInputPage && nextPage == this.myResultPage)
        getContainer().run(true, true, new MyCalculation());
}
```

The big advantage here is that the listener only gets called if the wizard wants to jump between pages, and we are able to really fine-tune the calculation (e.g. to not be called when calling 'Previous'). We are even able to not show the next page after all (`event.doit = false`).

The drawback is the cast of the container to `WizardDialog`, because potentially it could be an entirely different implementation.

So the question stands: What is the best way to start long processes in wizards?

Comment: To clarify: What you want is the ability to tell when a page is changing? (The fact that you want to run a long calculation is irrelevant to the question, since you already know how to run a long calculation)

Comment: @immibis Yes. And I don't think it's entirely irrelevant, since there are places that get notified of page changes that are not able to do a calculation based on wizard internals.

Comment: The wizard page has a `getContainer()` so you don't need to do `getWizard().getContainer()`. I don't understand what you think the problem with the `setVisible` method is.

Comment: @greg-449 I added a bigger example for why using `setVisible()` is wrong. The `getContainer()` does nothing to reduce that fact.